# DryIOC keeps disposing singleton objects

Tags: c#, xamarin, prism, dryioc

I have a Xamarin forms app that is using dryioc for IoC. It seems all my services get disposed as soon as the view is out of scope

This is how I am registering the service in the app.cs

```
 protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
 {
    
     containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IInboxService, InboxService>();;
 }
```

and I resolve it this way in the app.cs

```
               protected override void OnInitialized()
            {
                _started = DateTime.Now;
                InitializeComponent();
                InitializeAppSettings();
               Container.Resolve<ISyncService>().Init(new List<ISyncableService>
                {
                   Container.Resolve<IInboxService>()
                });
}
```

When I need to use it in a viewmodel I put it in the constructor like so.

```
  public class HomeViewModel {
     public HomeViewModel(InboxService inboxService) 
     {
    
     }
}
```

The singleton is respected but then it will dispose and create a new one when it needs it. Anyone else run into this ?

**Xamarin Version: 5.0.0.2125 

Prism Version: 8.1.97 

LocIOS Version: 8.1.97**

Comment: This [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46424751/avoid-singleton-repository-dryioc-when-using-dependency-injection) may provide you some help. The answer of it talks about disposable transient service. In addition, you can use the other IOC container such as the TinyIoCContainer which the [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection) recommends.

Comment: interesting case ill let you know it that helps ty ... the official documentation is from 2017 I don't see how thats going to help me in the long run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> public HomeViewModel(InboxService inboxService)

This injects a concrete `InboxService` instance, which is independent of the registration of interfaces that it might implement. If you want your singleton, request an `IInboxService`:

> public HomeViewModel(IInboxService inboxService)

I try to give a service implementing a certain interface a meaningful name that's more than just interface's name minus `I`, like `DummyInboxService`, `TestInboxService`, `ImapInboxService`, `Pop3InboxService`, `RemoteInboxService`... thus making clearer what the respective implementation actually does and helping finding these errors (most likely a typo anyway) early.